# Scala : Merge Sort using Futures timing out

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency, functional-programming

The following sequential Merge Sort returns the result very quickly :-

```
def mergeSort(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    def merge(xs: List[Int], ys: List[Int]): List[Int] = (xs, ys) match {
      case (Nil, _) => ys
      case (_, Nil) => xs
      case (x :: xs1, y :: ys1) => if (x <= y) x :: merge(xs1, ys) else y :: merge(xs, ys1)
    }
    val mid = xs.length / 2
    if (mid <= 0) xs
    else {
      val (xs1, ys1) = xs.splitAt(mid)



      merge(mergeSort(xs1), mergeSort(ys1))
    }
  }

  val newList = (1 to 10000).toList.reverse

  mergeSort(newList)
```

However, when I try to parallelize it using Futures, it times out :-

```
def mergeSort(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    def merge(xs: List[Int], ys: List[Int]): List[Int] = (xs, ys) match {
      case (Nil, _) => ys
      case (_, Nil) => xs
      case (x :: xs1, y :: ys1) => if (x <= y) x :: merge(xs1, ys) else y :: merge(xs, ys1)
    }
    val mid = xs.length / 2
    if (mid <= 0) xs
    else {
      val (xs1, ys1) = xs.splitAt(mid)
      val sortedList1 = Future{mergeSort(xs1)}
      val sortedList2 = Future{mergeSort(ys1)}

      merge(Await.result(sortedList1,5 seconds), Await.result(sortedList2,5 seconds))
    }
  }

  val newList = (1 to 10000).toList.reverse

  mergeSort(newList)
```

I get a Timeout exception. I understand that this is probably because this code spawns log2 10000 threads which adds a lot of delay as the Execution context Threadpool may not have that many threads.

1.) How do I exploit the inherent parallelism in merge sort and parallelize this code ?

2.) For what use cases are Futures useful and when should they be avoided ?

**Edit 1 : Refactored code based on the feedback I've gotten so far :-**

```
def mergeSort(xs: List[Int]): Future[List[Int]] = {

    @tailrec
    def merge(xs: List[Int], ys: List[Int], acc: List[Int]): List[Int] = (xs, ys) match {
      case (Nil, _) => acc.reverse ::: ys
      case (_, Nil) => acc.reverse ::: xs
      case (x :: xs1, y :: ys1) => if (x <= y) merge(xs1, ys, x :: acc) else merge(xs, ys1, y :: acc)
    }

    val mid = xs.length / 2
    if (mid <= 0) Future {
      xs
    }
    else {
      val (xs1, ys1) = xs.splitAt(mid)
      val sortedList1 = mergeSort(xs1)
      val sortedList2 = mergeSort(ys1)
      for (s1 <- sortedList1; s2 <- sortedList2) yield merge(s1, s2, List())
    }
  }
```

Comment: `Await` should almost never be used until the boundary of your program. Also, your `merge` function is not tail recursive, and will cause `StackOverflowError` on a list of size slightly bigger than 10000.

Comment: @ZiyangLiu Have made the merge Tail recursive . Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when using Futures, you should a) await as little as possible and prefer to work within Futures, and b) pay attention to which execution context you are using.

As an example of a), here's how you could change this:

```
def mergeSort(xs: List[Int]): Future[List[Int]] = {
  def merge(xs: List[Int], ys: List[Int]): List[Int] = (xs, ys) match {
    case (Nil, _) => ys
    case (_, Nil) => xs
    case (x :: xs1, y :: ys1) => if (x <= y) x :: merge(xs1, ys) else y :: merge(xs, ys1)
  }
  val mid = xs.length / 2
  if (mid <= 0) Future(xs)
  else {
    val (xs1, ys1) = xs.splitAt(mid)
    val sortedList1 = mergeSort(xs1)
    val sortedList2 = mergeSort(ys1)
    for (s1 <- sortedList1; s2 <- sortedList2) yield merge(s1, s2)
  }
}
val newList = (1 to 10000).toList.reverse

Await.result(mergeSort(newList), 5 seconds)
```

However there's still a ton of overhead here. Typically you would only parallelize significantly-sized chunks of work to avoid being dominated by overhead, which in this case would probably mean falling back to a single-threaded version when recursion reaches a list below some constant size.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you elaborate a bit on :-

'Pay attention to the Execution Context you are using' ?

Comment: Basically just that different execution contexts can lead to different performance impacts, so you should keep that in the back of your mind. It's something that's easy to forget since it's mostly just handled by invisible implicits. Often it doesn't matter, but sometimes it really does. This has a good overview: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html